# Sort number as well as statement associated with it

Tags: shell, sorting

I have a file in which first row contains the number and second row contains a statement associated with it and so on like the below example

```
     12
     stat1
     18
     stat2
     15
     stat3
```

But i need to print the output like sorting reversely as per numbers and so the statement related to it and print like this

```
     Time = 18
     Stat = stat2
     Time = 15
     Stat = stat3
     Time = 12
     Stat = stat1
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my exorcism:

```
cat <yourfile> | awk '{s[NR]=$0} END {for(i=1;i<NR;i=i+2) print s[i], s[i+1]}' | sort -r | awk '{printf "Time = %s\nStat = %s\n",$1,$2}'
```

Output also:

```
    # cat test.dat
    12
    stat1
    18
    stat2
    15
    stat3


   # cat test.dat | awk '{s[NR]=$0} END {for(i=1;i<NR;i=i+2) print s[i], s[i+1]}' | sort -r | awk '{printf "Time = %s\nStat = %s\n",$1,$2}'
    Time = 18
    Stat = stat2
    Time = 15
    Stat = stat3
    Time = 12
    Stat = stat1
```

Comment: but its not sorting it as per the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'if(/^\s+\d+/){$k=$_}else{$x{$k}=$_}END{for(sort {$b<=>$a} keys %x){print "time=$_\nStat=$x{$_}";}}' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat t6emp
     12
     stat1
     18
     stat2
     15
     stat3
> perl -lne 'if(/^\s+\d+/){$k=$_}else{$x{$k}=$_}END{for(sort {$b<=>$a} keys %x){print "time=$_\nStat=$x{$_}";}}' t6emp
time=     18
Stat=     stat2
time=     15
Stat=     stat3
time=     12
Stat=     stat1
```